# Spring AOP: exchanging information between methods

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop, cross-cutting-concerns

Suppose that I have a class called `MyServlet`, whose purpose is to respond to a user request:

```java
@Component
public class MyServlet
{
    public void accept(String clientName, int clientID)
    {
        System.out.println("Processing client:" + clientName + " with ID: " + clientID);
    }
}
```

Generally speaking, serving the request of a user might be something we want to log before we attempt it to debug our application. So I would really like it if I could have this behavior happen transparently before `accept()` is ever called. For this person, a `Helper` class can provide a logging functionality, which we will decorate with `@Before`:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Helper
{
    @Before("execution(public void show())")
    public void log()
    {
        System.out.println("Logging data...");
    }
}
```

But it would be really useful for me to be able to get the information that is provided to `accept()` (in this case, a `String` and an `int`) and pass it into `log()`, since it would allow me to log exactly the user and their ID into whatever logging store I use. How can I achieve this?

Comment: **(1)** `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` should be on a separate `@Configuration` class, not on a `@Component`. **(2)** Your aspect intercepts `show()`, but your sample method is named `accept(String, int)`. So I am confused about what you want to achieve. The code does not speak for itself. So please update the question, then notify us by commenting here.

Answer (score 1):

You can access proxied method's arguments by injection of `JoinPoint` instance and invoking `getArgs()` method on it. Sample snippet below.

```
@Before("execution(* com.sample.SomeClass.doSometning(..))")
public void doSomethingBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
   Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
   for (Object arg: args) {
       // do whatever you like with the arguments
   }
}
```